# I am writing a report in Report Builder (Digital Metaphors) and need to write a multi conditional If statement

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I am trying to write a multi conditional `IF` statement or an `IF` / AND `IF` statement in Report Builder Enterprise V20.03 build 182 and I am not having luck.
I am basically nesting `IF` statements, but output shows as if the first statement is always true. The code sample is below:

```
begin
```

if DayCnt9.Value = 'Days' ***//This if statement and next are the two that should be met for the Value := 90***
then begin
if WorkOrders['CompletedDate'] - (Variable1.Value + WorkOrders['GracePeriod']) < 1
then begin
Variable2.Font.Color := cLBlack;
Value := 90;
end
else begin
Variable2.Font.Color := cLRed ;
Value := 100;
end

-note   I removed the following code from the original question because it doesn't add to the context of the question.  "if (WorkOrders['CompletedDate'] > 2) //This is only looking to see if the WO is complete"

Comment: It took me a couple of hours and help from one of our (company I contract through) developers to come up with the ">2" to evaluate if the work order had a completed date.  I had tried <> null, <> nil, >1 to evaluate and non of the three worked.  I was concerned about the adding/subtracting integers from a Date without using DateAdd but it seems to work.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: A Delphi date as an integer is the number of days since 12/30/1899 so is unlikely to be <= 2.  Using the current date and another date to get days between and branching on that interval makes more sense.